# I have unknown devices attached to my wireless router

Tags: wireless-networking

I have two unknown devices attached to my wireless router. 
They are showing as:

**IPv4 devices**

```
192.168.0.11    UNKNOWN 80:ea:23:2b:a9:b2
192.168.0.2     UNKNOWN bc:30:7d:ca:d9:e1
```

**Ipv6 devices**

```
fe80::82ea:23ff:fe2b:a9b2   UNKNOWN 80:ea:23:2b:a9:b2
```

Ideally I would like to understand the source and therefore if required how to disconnect them.

Comment: Reminds me of this: http://bash.org/?5273

Comment: I wish it was! unfortunately not.

Comment: Either change the password, or change the SSID, or blacklist these MAC addresses.

Comment: Lookup the "nmap" command and you might find out more about the devices.

Comment: Change your wireless password. Then give the new password only to devices that you are sure you want on your wireless.

Answer (score 4):

The OUIs of both of those MAC addresses shows up in the IEEE OUI database as being registered to "Wistron Neweb Corp.", a Taiwanese manufacturer of Ethernet cards, set-top box/smart TV chipsets, and Internet-of-things/home security products, among other things. Google for their name and browse their site(s) and maybe you'll see something that helps you realize which device this is.

Note that those two MAC addresses *might* be from the same device, for example if it managed to get connected to your network via both Ethernet and Wi-Fi, or via Ethernet and HomePlug or G.Hn, or whatever.

Also note that some other company may be using a Wistron Neweb chipset or reference design in their product. So for example, it might still be your cable TV set-top box even if that box is from some other company.

Comment: Eventually tracked my "Wistron Neweb Corp" MAC address to a Sony Bravia TV.

Comment: @ClaireFurney How did you track it?

Comment: I can't exactly remember - but if I go Home > Settings > Network Setup > View Network settings and status on the TV, I can see the MAC address and current IP address there

Answer (score 3):

Its your sky box wireless card.  To confirm, on your sky remote - services - settings - details - wired and wireless mac address details.  Compare with your 'rogue' device

Comment: The OP has not mentioned that he has Sky. It seems a huge leap to just assume that it is in this case. Also he said he has TWO unknown devices.

Comment: @Burgi I have seen both vendorID's used in Sky boxes (ethernet and Wifi) as well. It's pretty likely. And for some reason most people (even those that should know better...) don't seem to realize that if you connect them to your LAN they will show up as a network device somewhere. Seems that in the back of their mind they still associate them with "TV" which they don't expect to see on the LAN.

Comment: @Tonny If the author can provide some references I will happily withdraw my objection.

Comment: @Burgi Fair enough :-)